# set theory without venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can set theory based questions be solved without venn Diagram?

I have shared a link below which shows that some set theory questions can be solved by using lines instead of circles(as in Venn Diagram)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-Ka6MO7imA

But Using that concept I tried solving the following question but couldnt. Can anybody help?

In a school of 150 students, 100 play cricket, 90 play football, 80 play hockey. Every student plays atleast one sport. If 20 students play only football, what is the maximum number of students who play both cricket and hockey but not football?

Comment: One can give a relatively simple verbal argument, motivated perhaps by a picture (Venn diagram).

Comment: I have drawn a rough diagram about what I am trying to say(in the link below)......the 3 lines need to be arranged in such a way that the their common area is minimal.....with 2 variables this line method is very easy, but for 3 variables i cant figure out how to get it                                                                https://awwapp.com/s/93/10/cf.png

Comment: One can give an argument without any images whatsoever. We have that 90 play football and we're looking for the maximum number such that (so and so) and don't play football. The rest of the information seems like a decoy to me. 

After watching the video in the OP, you can solve this with the same strategy as in the video, you just need a line for "don't like football".

But apart from this, why do you not want to use Venn diagrams?

Comment: If i draw venn diagrams, then I have to write 3 or more equations, and solving becomes tricky. By using lines, the question looks more pictorial.